# ERROR: XX000: Materialized view could not be created on redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, materialized-views

```
Hi everyone,

I am trying to create a materialized view and command throwing the below error. Are there any restrictions on redshift materialized view? Kindly assist me here. 

**ERROR: XX000: Materialized view could not be created.**
```

CREATE  MATERIALIZED VIEW tbcdbv.tbc_delivery_aggregator_MV1
--BACKUP NO AUTO REFRESH NO
AS
SELECT
a.store_number as restid,
COALESCE(A.dw_restid, B.dw_restid) AS dw_restid
, COALESCE(A.dw_day, B.dw_day) AS dw_day
,COALESCE(A.fiscalweekno, B.fiscalweekno) AS fiscalweekno
, COALESCE(A.order_submission_date::date , B.order_submission_date::date ) AS business_date
, COALESCE(A.delivery_id , B.dd_order_number ) AS delivery_id
, COALESCE(A.client_order_id , B.client_order_id ) AS client_order_id
, COALESCE(A.external_pos_id , B.client_order_id ) AS external_pos_id
, COALESCE(A.order_status, B.order_status) AS order_status
, store_name
, street_address
, city
, country
, COALESCE(A.week , B.week) AS week
, CASE
WHEN COALESCE(A.IS_CONSUMER_PICKUP, B.IS_CONSUMER_PICKUP) = FALSE THEN 'Delivery'
WHEN COALESCE(A.IS_CONSUMER_PICKUP, B.IS_CONSUMER_PICKUP) = TRUE THEN 'Pick Up'
ELSE 'Not Listed'
END AS retrieval
, is_scheduled_order
, COALESCE(A.is_dashpass_order, B.is_dashpass ) AS is_dashpass_order
, order_scheduled_time
, A.count_of_skus AS count_of_skus
, COALESCE(A.food_subtotal_local, B.food_subtotal_local) AS food_subtotal
, COALESCE(A.tax_subtotal_local, B.tax_subtotal_local) AS tax_subtotal
, A.tax_remitted_by_doordash_local AS tax_remitted_by_aggregator_local
, COALESCE(A.commission_rate / 100.00, B.commission_rate / 100.00) AS commission_rate
, COALESCE(A.commission, B.commission) AS commission
, COALESCE(A.marketing_fee, B.marketing_fee) AS marketing_fee
, COALESCE(A.currency, B.currency) AS currency
, b.store_charge
, b.store_refund
, b.net_payout
, c.aggregator_id
, aggregator_name
, markup_percentage
, store_confirmed_time
, dasher_arrived_at_store_time
, pickup_time
, COALESCE(A.delivered_time::timestamp , B.delivered_time::timestamp )as  delivered_time
, customer_rating
, customer_comments
, COALESCE(A.order_submission_date_timestamp::timestamp , B.order_submission_date_timestamp::timestamp )as  order_submission_date_timestamp
, COALESCE(A.original_file_name, B.original_file_name ) AS original_file_name
, COALESCE(A.created_date::timestamp , B.created_date::timestamp )as  created_date
, COALESCE(A.updated_date::timestamp , B.updated_date::timestamp )as  updated_date
FROM
tbcdb.doordash_weekly_sales_summary a
FULL OUTER JOIN tbcdb.doordash_weekly_payment b ON
a.delivery_id = b.dd_order_number
AND a.dw_restid = b.dw_restid
AND a.dw_day = b.dw_day
left outer join tbcdb.tbc_delivery_markup c
on a.dw_restid = c.dw_restid
inner join tbcdb.tbc_aggregator_dim e
on c.aggregator_id = e.aggregator_id
inner join tbcdb.align_dim d
on a.store_number = d.restid
where tbc_opr_brand ='Y' and status_cd in ('OPN','CLT')
and c.aggregator_id=6"

Comment: Does the error message offer any suggestions as to _why_ the view cannot be created?  Most people reading this question will not be able to add any information on top of what you already know.

Comment: First: you've put your question in as `code`, and left the view definition as plain text, which makes it completely unreadable.

Comment: Second: how are you creating this view? Are you using an interactive tool such as `psql`, or programmatically? If the latter, I recommend trying to create it interactively, as there's almost certainly additional information about what failed.

Comment: Third: that's a very complex view. The best way to build out a complex view is to start with a simple view. Add one source / set of predicates at a time, and look at what changed if/when the create fails.

Comment: Does the select run standalone, outside of the CREATE VIEW statement?